# How do I zip a directory of files using C++?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, compression, zlib

I'm working on a project using C++, Boost, and Qt. I understand how to compress single files and bytestreams using, for example, the qCompress() function in Qt.

How do I zip a directory of multiple files, including subdirectories? I am looking for a cross-platform (Mac, Win, Linux) solution; I'd prefer not to fire off a bunch of new processes.

Is there a standard way to combine bytestreams from multiple files into a zipped archive, or maybe there is a convenience function or method that would be available in the Boost iostream library?

Many thanks for the assistance.

**Update**: The QuaZip library looks really great. There is an example in the download package (in the "tests" dir) that shows very clearly how to zip up a directory of files.

**Update 2**: After completing this task on my Linux build environment, I discovered that QuaZip doesn't work at all with the Visual Studio compiler. It may be possible to tackle all those compiler errors, but a word of caution to anyone looking down this path.

Comment: http://www.zlib.net/

Comment: As far as I am aware, zlib only supports .gz files and not .zip files.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for .zip. The minizip library linked from the zlib.net site might be able to help, but I need to dig into it a little more... If anyone knows more about this library I'd appreciate hearing about it.

Comment: Can you actually compress whole directories with zlib? Or just single files?

Comment: Zlib only does single files - you need another package format to handle the files and directories

Comment: You can compress whole directories with minizip (can be found in zlib/contrib/minizip) but you will have to iterate over directory's contents and add the files one by one (boost::filesystem can help).

Comment: @AdamPierce No! The compressed data streams are almost always deflate data streams, which can in fact be generated and decoded by `zlib` indeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the following two libraries:

- [ZipIOS++](http://zipios.sf.net). Seems to be "pure" C++. They don't list Windows explicitly as a supported platform. So i think you should try your luck yourself.
- [QuaZIP](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/index.html). Based on Qt4. Actually looks nice. They list Windows explicitly (Using mingw). Apparently, it is a C++ wrapper for [this] library.

Ah, and of course, i have ripped those sites from [this](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-07/thread00070-0.html) Qt Mailinglist question about Zipping/Unzipping of directories :)

Comment: QuaZip looks like the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: ZipIOS++ does have MSVC 6 project files. However, it borrows some code from Boost.Filesystem (as of 2001!), which doesn't really compile out of the box, at least in my VS2008 environment. So I guess I'll also have to look at QuaZIP, or plain zlib...

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record...

Today, I needed to do something very similar in Visual C++. (Though wanted to maintain the possibility to compile the project on other platforms; however preferred not to adopt Qt just for this purpose.)

Ended up using the [Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) library. It is written in plain C, but devising a simple C++ wrapper around it was a breeze, and the end result works great, at least for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I have built a wrapper around minizip adding some features that I needed and making it nicer to use it. Is does use the latest c++11 and is developed using Visual Studio 2013, so it should work out-of-the-box for you.

There's a full description here: https://github.com/sebastiandev/zipper

you can zip entire folders, streams, vectors, etc. Also a nice feature is doing everything entirely in memory.

Answer (score 1):

`Poco::Zip` is also a choice, it has clearly documentation and some code for demo.

[Poco::Zip Document](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Zip.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
system("zip myarchive.zip *");
```

Comment: He said he doesn't want to fire off new processes.

Comment: This is only one extra process and its a helluva lot quicker to implement than using a 3rd party library. But, I don't know the reasons for not wanting to launch another process, maybe the OP has very limited memory or wants more control over ZIP as it is running but this is how I'd do it.

Comment: it's not a question of spawning new processes. this answer is just plain ignorant. what if "zip" is not installed, what about other platforms then unix?

Answer (score 0):

I tried QuaZIP 0.4.3 on Windows with VisualStudio 2010 -- there are still issues but can be resolved easily.

## To build with VS:

1. Use CMake to configure and generate VS solution for QuaZIP.
2. Open soltion with VS and build -- you'll first notice that it can't find 'zlib.h'.
3. Open preferences for quazip project and add path to Qt's copy of Zlib to C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories: $(QTDIR)/src/3rdparty/zlib.
4. Rebuild again and you'll get lots of warnings and one error C2491: dllimport static issue on QuaZipFile::staticMetaObject.
5. This is because QuaZipFile is declared like "class QUAZIP_EXPORT QuaZipFile" and QUAZIP_EXPORT needs to resolve to Q_DECL_EXPORT for dll and to Q_DECL_IMPORT for application, based on whether QUAZIP_BUILD is defined or not.  When building QuaZIP QUAZIP_BUILD should be defined but isn't -- configuration process defines in error completely useless "quazip_EXPORTS" instead.
6. To fix, just remove "quazip_EXPORTS" from all build configurations and add QUAZIP_BUILD instead -- QuaZIP will now build fine.