# What is the best library to work with archives

Tags: c++, api, cross-platform, archive

I wonder, what library you would choose for the following:
I need to be able to combine a bunch of files and folders (a tree of filesystem structure) into one file - archive, thus having one composite file.

- the library must be cross-platform: Windows 7 and Linux
- it must provide access to the content and ability to extract only one file (e.g. if I have an archive of data folder and if I need only data/subdata/file, only it should be extracted)
- it must have C++ (preferably) or C API
- I am not particularly keen on archiving, but it would be desirable, since I will be storing mostly text files and they compress well...

Any feedback is highly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at bit7z library. Looks very promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) in combination with [Boost Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iostreams/doc/home.html) is a great combination. This does not do file level extraction though.

EDIT:
Some other options I found via [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505863/how-do-i-zip-a-directory-of-files-using-c) include:

- [Zipios++](http://zipios.sourceforge.net/)
- [QuaZIP](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/index.html) - Requires QT, may not build on Windows
  correctly

EDIT2:

- [Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) (usually included with zlib) will do the trick too - probably the most lightweight and commonly used solution.

Comment: Doesn't provide the composite part OP asks for.

Answer (score 2):

Consider libarchive.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libarchive.htm

Answer (score 0):

[zlib](http://zlib.net/) is probably the safe answer.

Comment: Big drawback of libarchive is disastrous UTF-8 handling of file names. It seems there are workarounds with setting locale on macOS and Linux but no workaround for me on Windows. Otherwise it is a great library.